# mutate/replace JSON object on event listener

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable filtered that holds a large object from sql. And I have generated a table with it as follows. Now in order for me to let the user filter data, I want to show rows that are only with a specific attribute: 
This is how my table generated on document ready, I removed the head section from this question for now. 
Live here: http://klaussongs.com/

```
var renderer = {
    text: function(data) {
        return data;
    },
    link: function(data) {
        return '<a href="' + data + '">View</a>';
    }
};

var config = [
    {attr: "Carat", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Color", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Shape", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Cut", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Symmetry", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Report", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Clarity", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "Polish", renderer: renderer.text},
    {attr: "link_view", renderer: renderer.link}
];

filtered.forEach(function(data) {

    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    config.forEach(function(entry) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td"),
            value = data[entry.attr];
        cell.innerHTML = entry.renderer(value);
        row.appendChild(cell);
    });
  table.appendChild(row);    

});
```

Now when someone click on an option to see only rows that have attribute shape of "Princess" for example, I can run a query such as:

```
//this variable is for one of the possible shapes, there are 8 more, 

let shapePrincess = document.getElementById("shape-princess");
shapePrincess.addEventListener('click', function() { 
  for (var i  =0; i<filtered.length;i++){if(filtered[i].Shape = "Princess"){
    console.log(filtered[i]);

  }};
```

please notice I am not going back to fetch any data from database anymore, I just want to mutate or change/replace the current generated table with this newly selected option. Right now when I console this code I get all products that have "Princess" shape but how do I replace it with the currently generated table? and not append to it. I am also looking for a way where I can apply it to all my shapes. It's basically a filter option of select and show. They can also select multiple shape as well. but the problem is that my function append and not replace. 
All helps are appreciated in advance.

Comment: did you try Clearing that table before appending new data?

Comment: no but if I clear table each time the previous filter gets removed as well. I want them to be select one shape push those rows up and select new shape push new shapes on top of previously filtered

Comment: and how would i clean this table

Comment: please upload an example with some test-data, that would help to understand the problem

Comment: I added a link above.you can see if you click on any of the shapes in console you will see all those shape populates.

Comment: Why don't you just generate that big table, and add a class to every row? When the user wants to filter a category, you just hide()/Show() all elements with that class.

Comment: How can I target and delete appended rows?

Comment: give them a class and find them by class, then remove them. but still, i thinks its better to just hide/show them instead of genertaing and remove dom elements